# Python selenium много ошибок

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Делаю код, используя selenium, и при запуске скрипта через батник получил тонну ошибок не слишком понятного содержания, потому что я даже понятия не имел о таких файлах, который там указаны

Вот скрипт:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\...\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://google.com')

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input"]')
search.send_keys('Морковь')
```

А вот ошибка при запуске:

```
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 84, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\conf.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\...\chromedriver.exe")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

Comment: Код вроде выглядит нормально, попробуй: 
Обновить Selenium, ChromeDriver.

Проверь правильный ли XPath указал

Comment: С версией selenium все хорошо, Xpath проверял, но вот насчёт chromedriver я хз, у меня две версии хрома, одна неправильная и другая под мою версию chromedriver, возможно, он обращается не к той версии, но как это указать я не в курсах

Answer (score 0):

Проверяем, обновляем: Selenium, [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/).
Проверяем правильный ли XPath указал.

Возможно проблема связана с тем, что версия ChromeDriver не совпадает с версией установленного Chrome на твоем пк. Нужно удостовериться, что установлена совместимая версия ChromeDriver.

Попробуй явно указать путь к chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_driver_path = r"C:\путь\к\chromedriver.exe"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  # Опционально: запускать браузер в полноэкранном режиме

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://google.com')

search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')  # используй свой селектор
search.send_keys('Морковь')
```

// Дальше твой код

Обращаю внимание, что в: webdriver.Chrome() нужно указать твой путь к chromedriver.